# Hive import from HDFS as ORC

Tags: hive

I exported a hive table in hdfs using

`export table abc to '/tmp/123'`

It created two directories `/data` and `/metadata` and keeps data and metadata accordingly.

Now I sent this data to another hadoop cluster using **distcp** command.

Now I want to import this data in a table xyz (*not created yet*)

Now using hive import command

`import table xyz from '/tmp/123'`

It created Table xyz with data but in text format.

I want this xyz in ORC format.

Yes, I can create another table using this text table.

Is there any better way for that ??

Can I mention anywhere in command?

Comment: If you want to *clone* the original table -- just run the same exact CREATE TABLE script in target cluster (and the same exact CREATE PARTITIONS if it's partitioned) and `distcp` the source directory to target directory. That's it. Text to Text, ORC to ORC, etc.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter agree with you. But what about text to ORC?

Comment: Did you try to create an EXTERNAL table, on the target Hive Metastore, with a location on `hdfs://source.namenode:port/path/to/CSV`, so that you can INSERT-SELECT directly without bothering to `distcp` first?